# Python Classes did I make a mistake or did my teacher [easy]

Tags: python, class, structure

My teacher told us to make a `Clock` class that will take `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` as instance variables. He then gave us a bunch of different methods we had to make to complete objectives he gave us regarding the `Clock` class.

One of our tasks was to implement a method called `print12()` that prints out the time with colons and appends AM or PM to the end. He asked us to test it by entering `print12(myclock)`. Mine only works if I enter `myclock.print12()`. I'm not sure if he made an error or I implemented my code wrong.

Here is my code:

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, hour, minute, second):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second
    def __str__(self):
        return '%02d'%self.hour+':'+'%02d'%self.minute+':'+'%02d'%self.second
    def print12(self):
        if self.hour >= 13:
            print(self,"P.M.")
        else:
            print(self,"A.M.")
    def advance(self,s1):
        if s1 == 'sec':
            self.second += 1
        elif s1 == 'min':
            self.minute += 1
        elif s1 == 'hour':
            self.hour += 1
        if self.second == 60:
            self.second = 0
            self.minute += 1
        if self.minute == 60:
            self.minute = 0
            self.hour += 1
        if self.hour == 24:
            self.hour = 0
            self.minute = 0
            self.second = 0
```

Here is his main code to test the program:

```
myclock = Clock(15,59,5)
print(myclock)
print12(myclock)
myclock.advance('sec')
print(myclock)
myclock.advance('min')
print(myclock)
```

This does not work for me but will work if I replace `print12(myclock)` with `myclock.print12()`.

Comment: We can't guess your teacher's intentions. You should ask him for clarifications.

Comment: I think the instructor is trying to introduce classmethods..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on your reporting, the teacher likely meant one of two things:

1) Create a method of `Clock` that prints as indicated:

```
class Clock:
    ...
    def print12(self):
        if self.hour >= 13:
            print(self,"P.M.")
        else:
            print(self,"A.M.")

 # Usage:
 myclock=Clock(...)
 myclock.print12()
```

2) Create a function, outside of `Clock`, which takes a `Clock` as an argument and prints as indicated:

```
class Clock:
    ...

def print12(clock):
    if clock.hour >= 13:
        print(clock,"P.M.")
    else:
        print(clock,"A.M.")

# Usage:
myclock = Clock(...)
print12(myclock)
```

You'll need to ask your instructor which he meant.

Comment: Thank you I'm sure it is the second one since that's what he asked us to use

Comment: A third possibility is that the instructor wanted you to write an instance method (as in the first example) but then wanted you to pass the instance in manually. This works if you grab the unbound method directly the class: `Clock.print12(myclock)`. This isn't as natural as using bound methods, but it is sometimes necessary (and certainly worth learning about).

Answer (score 2):

The `print12` function is only defined inside the `Clock` class, so it should be called on instances of that class. Hence, `myclock.print12` is the proper way.